# Yii2 don't translate system messages/validators

Tags: yii2, multilingual, translate

I have app on ru language.
After configurating and add Chinese there is left some phrases on Eng. I check \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\messages\zh-CN\yii.php, but still see: Please fix the following errors.

Also tried edit messages on DB - not results.

How to fix it?

```
'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'app*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'ru-RU',
                    'on missingTranslation' => ['app\components\TranslationEventHandler', 'handleMissingTranslation'],
                ],
                'yii' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'ru-RU',
                    'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Try to add `'forceTranslation' => true,` after `'sourceLanguage'`

Comment: Tried before posting and now - no result.

Answer (score 0):

Just change language app in

config.php

```
return [
  ...
  'language' => 'zh-CN',
  ...
];
```

And remove `'i18n'` from `config.php` if you don't have custom messages

Comment: I have switch-button for 3 languages. When I choose eng or ru - system message translated (to ru or eng). But for Cn - no (eng translate).

Comment: If you use differents languajes in your app, you must copy the folders of translation  (originals of yii)  into the @app/message folder

Comment: What if I don't use messages (DB storage) ?